# Change data in the tui-calender using db data in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.8

I am using a tui calendar in a project. Here I get a tui-calender with dummy data.I need to show that calendar data based on my DB data. Here I have an only class table. there I have a date, start time, end time and class details, etc. I need to show the data's on the corresponding date.
[this is the calendar template.](https://www.pixinvent.com/demo/frest-clean-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-template/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template/app-calendar.html)

[image: this is getting error of tuicalnder]

I copied the contents and run it. it is showing the same as the template in my Laravel blade.
here now I need to change the data on the corresponding date. and I need to display data of DB there. I am passing the online class details in the Laravel blade through the controller.

```
<script type="">
      var Calendar = tui.Calendar;
      var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
        defaultView: 'month',
        taskView: true,
        template: {
          monthGridHeader: function(model) {
            var date = new Date(model.date);
            var template = '<span class="tui-full-calendar-weekday-grid-date">' + date.getDate() + '</span>';
            return template;
          }
        }
      });

      @foreach($onlineClass as $appointment)
        calendar.createSchedules([
          {
            'title' : '{{ $appointment->teacher}}',
            'start' : '{{ $appointment->start_time }}',
            'end' : '{{ $appointment->end_time }}',
            'isReadOnly' : true
          },
        ]); 
      @endforeach
    </script>
```

Comment: plz help me to solve this

Comment: With the information you have provided us, I don't believe there is any way we can give you a solution.

Comment: is there any scripts available to add the data, from controller i get the online class details and then appending those datas

Comment: hai, 
please firends it is very toough , i cannot correct this issue. plz help me to solve

Comment: When it says that `tui` is not defined, then it means what you haven't included the tui js correctly. Ty add `https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/dist/tui-calendar.js` right after your script.

Comment: i added that, but the issue is now there having two calenders one is the dummy detailed calender and another calender without any datas

Comment: @foreach($onlineClass as $appointment)
        calendar.createSchedules([
          {
            'title' : '{{ $appointment->teacher}}',
            'start' : '{{ $appointment->start_time }}',
            'end' : '{{ $appointment->end_time }}',
            'isReadOnly' : true
          },
        ]); 
      @endforeach
is this correct script